# ajax datatype JSON in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to send dataType `JSON` in plain javascript. in Jquery, following way working and returning data successfully.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:{sts:'student'},
    dataType:"JSON",
    success: function(data){
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But while switching to plain JavaScript. I've added `http.responseType = 'json';`

```
var http = null;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
http.open('POST','fetch.php',true);
http.responseType = 'json';
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
        var data = http.responseText;
    }
}
http.send('sts=student');
```

but it thrown error;

> InvalidStateError: responseText is only available if responseType is
>   '' or 'text'.

I've changed `http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`
to `http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');` but same error.

Comment: Have you tried setting responseType to "text" and setting data to `JSON.parse(http.responseText)`?

Comment: use `var data = http.response;` - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response)